# Tuleap Installation prerequisite packages?

Tags: installation, tuleap

I am trying to install Tuleap on a clean CentOS 6 Server. I cant find a list of prerequisite packages. Do I need MySQL, Apache, PHP, etc? Or does the Tuleap install handle those?

I have tried a few times and get a lot of skipped packages due to prerequisites missing. I have not been able to find the information in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The list of dependencies is defined in the RPMs themselves. You just have to install the packages mentioned in the [installation guide](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html) and everything should work seamlessly.